# How long you can consider a pending transaction as invalid?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I saw [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26190/how-long-to-wait-for-pending-transactions) that the time that a transaction can be at pending status changed, but didn't say how much

> Due to overwhelming amounts of pending transactions during ICOs, many public nodes (etherscan, MEW, infura) adjusted their settings in order to keep more transactions in a pending state for a longer period of time.

Currently I'm studying relations in pending transactions over Ethereum blockchain, so I'd like to know how much time I can stop searching for a pending transaction, as it may cause ripple in my database, since new transactions with same data can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set limit. Every node can have its own limit, and the limit tends to depend on how many transactions there are in the pool. There isn't a way to know how long a transaction can be considered pending. A transaction could be mined years later assuming the nonce hadn't been used.